# SQL zoonet more join operation #10

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on SQL Zoo.Net more join operations. Here is the link to the question: 
http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/More_JOIN_operations

The question is #10 : List the films together with the leading star for all 1962 films. I have got the correct answer for this question which is

```
SELECT movie.title, actor.name
FROM movie
JOIN casting
ON casting.movieid = movie.id
JOIN actor
ON actor.id = casting.actorid
WHERE movie.yr = 1962
AND casting.ord = 1
```

But I came up with my own version and it doesn't work throwing the error as too few columns. I am trying to understand what is the problem with my query. I am not very proficient in SQL so my understanding of how it works might be wrong and my question might seem stupid. Here is my query that doesn't work. Please explain as to why the upper query is working fine and why my query doesn't work.

```
select Title,actor.name as Actors
from movie
right join actor
on director = actor.id
where actor.id IN  ( select actorid
                    from casting
                    where movieid IN (select id
                                      from movie
                                      where yr = 1962
                                )
                    and ord = 1
                   )
order by title
```

Comment: "too few columns"? I don't know that error. What is the exact error message? What dbms do you use?

Comment: @HoneyBadger Thanks for replying. The error is 'too few rows' though it is still returning some rows. The DBMS is MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

solution for : SQL Zoo.Net more join operations Question number 10

```
select movie.title,actor.name from movie
join casting on movie.id = casting.movieid and casting.ord = 1 and movie.yr=1962
join actor on actor.id = casting.actorid
```

Explanation:-

First join the table of movie and casting with use of fields movieid and ord and yr conditions.

second that (movie and actor)joined table join to actor with use of field actorid.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, and thank you for your answer. Rather than just posting a block of code, can you give a short explanation to what the issue is you solved and how you solved it? This will help people who find this question in the future to better understand the issue and how to deal with it.

Comment: Thanks @Plutian for your valuable comment, I edited to update my solution.

Answer (score 0):

My solution

```
SELECT title, name
FROM movie JOIN casting ON (movie.id = casting.movieid)
JOIN actor ON (casting.actorid = actor.id)
WHERE ord = 1 AND yr = 1962
```

This works too